# How to bind NSArrayController to another NSArrayController were it has NSSet

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I'm working on OS X app where I have a core data model like this:

Movies <--->>Theaters

I have bind an NSArrayController to the entity of the Movies in NSPopUpButton when I make a selections I should see the list of Theaters where the movie is playing.

In my Movies class header:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *theaters;
```

and my Theater class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * theaterName;
```

I tried to set the binding to "Content Set" but loads only the initial set and doesn't change the content when I switch the selection in the NSPopUpButton (Movies).

Any of you knows why always show the content related to the firs selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

First `NSArrayController`: set its entity to be `Movie`. Bind it to the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Second `NSArrayController`: set its entity to be `Theatre`. Bind it to the `NSManagedObjectContext`, and bind its `Content Set` to the `moviesArrayController.selection.theatres`.

Then I have two popup:
The first one has its content bound to `moviesArrayController.arrangedObjects`. Also its `selectedIndex` is bound to `moviesArrayController.selectionIndex`.
The second popup is simply bound the the theatres controller.arrangedObjects.

Comment: Thank you, having the sample project help me a lot. I really appreciate.

Comment: Looks like the sample project isn't there anymore.  It might be better to edit the answer with screencaps rather than link to external (ephemeral) examples.